# Leaflet does not show local image as overlay

Tags: javascript, html, leaflet

I'm trying to show my my image via leaflet. My HTML and Image files are located in same folder. My images size is **1920x1080**

I searched from internet and I have written this code:

```
<div id="map"></div>
<script>
    var map = L.map('map', {
    maxZoom: 20,
    minZoom: 20,
    crs: L.CRS.Simple
    }).setView([0, 0], 20);

    var imageUrl = 'test.jpg';
    var southWest = map.unproject([1920, 0], map.getMaxZoom());
    var northEast = map.unproject([0, 1080], map.getMaxZoom());

    map.setMaxBounds(new L.LatLngBounds(southWest, northEast));

    var imageBounds = [[1920, 0], [0, 1080]];

    L.imageOverlay(imageUrl, imageBounds).addTo(map);
</script>
```

Map has style:

```
<style>
    #map { height: 480px; }
</style>
```

When I open my HTML file, leaflet shows nothing but grey background.

Did I miss something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to `unproject()` the coordinates.

`unproject` turns map coordinates into *screen pixel* coordinates. **You do not want to do that** unless you are measuring screen pixels or positioning custom elements on the screen.

Without having a look at a live example, I can only guess that you're setting the map's bounds to an area outside the coverage of your image.